# AS3: How to add linkage in array?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to AS3 so please excuse me if the question is a bit confusing.

I have 3 movieclips in my library with the Linkage names "Panel1", "Panel2" and "Panel3".

I want to create a new Array on my main timeline with the three movieclips.

i.e. `var panelArray = new Array(Panel1, Panel2, Panel3);`

How would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add the movieClips to array then:

```
var panelArray = new Array( new Panel1 (), new Panel2 (), new Panel3 ());
```

and you will be able to access them like:

```
panelArray[0] // for Panel1;
panelArray[1] // for Panel2;
panelArray[2] // for Panel3;
```

if you need to add just class name to the array as you did it is good:

```
var panelArray = new Array(Panel1, Panel2, Panel3);
```

And when you want access them:

```
new panelArray[0] () // for Panel1;
new panelArray[1] () // for Panel2;
new panelArray[2] () // for Panel3;
```

In the first array, the mc's are created on adding them to the array, and when you accessing them you get the `DisplayObject` directly. In the second array the array holds just a names of the classes, from which you can create a `DisplayObject` for futher uses.

Comment: Thank you, the 1st one is just what I need!